# Magento 1.9 Wrong permission on cahed images

Tags: magento-1.9

I have moved a Magento from one server to another.
Now images are broken when Magento creates the thumbnails. If I chenged the permissions to 777 for folders and 644 for files via FTP, everythig is fine, but the next image that is generated is wrong again.

I have checked the uploader.php file, but the permission set in the code is correct.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the files *owner*. Maybe the web-server users are different from server1 and server2, and when magento creates the new images, the permission fails.

If i remember correctly, magento expects the web-server user to own the project assets, you could try to change the file ownership:

```
chown -R your-weserver-user:your-webserver-user-group /your/magento/app/assets_folder
```

also, check this other thread: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99646/image-uploads-using-wrong-permissions